# Registration of chrooted environment on Landscape not working with Virtual license

Tags: landscape, chroot, license

Despite having several remaining registrations on Landscape, it doesn't let me register chrooted environments:
'There are no licenses available for $accountname. $hostname was not accepted.'

License type: Virtual
Seats free: 12

How should I add those chrooted environments to Landscape?

Comment: A chrooted environment is not a virtual environment as there is no isolation; the environment shares the same devices, address space, uids/gids, network configuration. For all practical purpose, a chroot IS the same physical machine. If you're looking for lightweight virtualization, LXD/LXC is probably what you're looking for as it does just enough isolation to make the container distinct from the host system.

Comment: Right, thanks. The chroot are running, I guess it's more an issue with the license type then.

Comment: Those chrooted environments (precise) are running on VMs (xenial) that have not been added to landscape. I'm trying to get Ubuntu ESM for the chroot envs. Is someone able to tell the licenses I'd need?

Comment: Hi Benoit -- Ubuntu ESM is a commercial product offered by Canonical, for help using it, please file a support request with Canonical.  FYI, Canonical does not support landscape running in a chroot.  Only a system container, VM or physical system.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ESM is a commercial product offered by Canonical, for help using it, please file a support request with Canonical.

FYI, Canonical does not support landscape running in a chroot. Only a system container, VM or physical system.